# Getting a generic list using reflection always null

Tags: c#, reflection

**The Problem:**

Hey folks, I am having a strange issue that is starting to really frustrate me. I have searched high and low for the answer, and tried many different things, but for some reason I cannot get this code working.

I am using reflection to to convert an array of anonymous objects to specific types, based on the type of **T**. Now before it is mentioned, yes reflection is the only way to do what I am doing (converting a script language to Type Strong C# objects).

My issue is on lines 35 - 43. If the value type is that of a List{T}, then I first check if it is null... If so, I create a new list using Activator.CreateInstance() (line 58), otherwise use the existing list. The issue I am facing here is that the Value is ALWAYS NULL when this method is called, even though I am setting the Value on line 43. That means the list will never have more than 1 item in it, even if I am adding more than 1 item...

On lines 23 and 51, you can see that I set the Value for other types, and it works perfectly, so what am I doing wrong on lines 34-43 that are preventing this code from working correctly?

**The Code:**

You can view this code with line numbers on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tVVvSpX9) or below:

```
public class ObjectProperty<T> : ObjectPropertyBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the value for this property
    /// </summary>
    public T Value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes an array of string values, and converts it to the proper value type for
    /// this instance's Generic Type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ValueParams">The string value's to convert, and set the
    /// Value of this instance to.
    /// </param>
    public override void SetValueFromParams(String[] ValueParams)
    {
        Type PropertyType = typeof(T);

        // Check for array's, as they are handled differently
        if (PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            // Set the value to the instanced object
            Value = (T)ConvertArray(ValueParams, PropertyType);
        }
        else if (PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            // Grab our types interfaces and generic types
            Type[] interfaces = PropertyType.GetInterfaces();
            Type[] types = PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

            // Check for List<T>
            if (interfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(IList)))
            {
                // Grab our current list... if the Value isnt created yet, make it
                dynamic obj = (dynamic)Value ?? CreateList(types);

                // Add our value to the list
                if (types[0].IsArray)
                    obj.Add(ConvertArray(ValueParams, types[0]));
                else
                    obj.Add(ConvertValue<dynamic>(ValueParams[0], types[0]));

                Value = (T)obj;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception($"Invalid Generic Type found \"{PropertyType}\"");
        }
        else
        {
            // Since we are not an array, extract our only value
            Value = ConvertValue<T>(ValueParams[0], PropertyType);
        }
    }

    protected static IList CreateList(Type[] genericTypes)
    {
        Type obj = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericTypes);
        return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the object value into the Typed variant of this <see cref="Value"/>
    /// </summary>
    protected K ConvertValue<K>(object Value, Type PropertyType)
    {
        // No need to change type if types match
        if (Value.GetType() == PropertyType)
            return (K)Value;

        // Enums need special care
        if (PropertyType.IsEnum)
            return (K)Enum.Parse(PropertyType, Value.ToString(), true);

        return (K)Convert.ChangeType(Value, PropertyType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the object array values into the Typed variant of this <see cref="Value"/>
    /// </summary>
    protected object ConvertArray(Object[] values, Type propertyType)
    {
        // Set the value to the instanced object
        switch (propertyType.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "int[]":
            case "int32[]":
                return Array.ConvertAll(values, Convert.ToInt32);
            case "string[]":
                return Array.ConvertAll(values, Convert.ToString);
            case "double[]":
                return Array.ConvertAll(values, Convert.ToDouble);
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid property type: " + propertyType.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for having a look at my problem, hopefully someone can help me get this figured out.

**EDIT**: Call to Method

```
public class Example
{
    [PropertyName("isExample")]
    public ObjectProperty<bool> IsExample;

    // .....

    public void Parse(string[] Params)
    {
        // Fetch our property that we are setting the value to
        FieldInfo prop = this.GetType().GetField("isExample");

        // Create our instance, and parse
        ObjectPropertyBase obj = ObjectPropertyBase.Create(prop);
        obj.SetValueFromParams(Params);
        prop.SetValue(this, obj);
    }
}    
    // Base Class

    public abstract class ObjectPropertyBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Takes an array of string values, and converts it to the proper value type for
        /// this instance's Generic Type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ValueParams">The string value's to convert, and set the 
        /// Value of this instance to.
        /// </param>
        public abstract void SetValueFromParams(String[] value);

        /// <summary>
        ///     Using reflection, this method creates a new instance of the <paramref name="field"/>
        ///     type, and returns it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        ///     This method does NOT set the field value, since hey... we dont have an instance to work on
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="field">The field we are creating an instance for. </param>
        /// <exception cref="System.Exception">
        ///     Thrown if the Field provided does not contain the <see cref="PropertyName"/> attribute
        /// </exception>
        public static ObjectPropertyBase Create(FieldInfo field)
        {
            // If the Custom attribute exists, we add it to the Mapping
            Attribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(PropertyName));
            if (attribute == null)
                throw new Exception($"Internal property \"{field.Name}\" does not contain a PropertyName attribute!");

            // Get our constructor
            PropertyName fieldAttr = attribute as PropertyName;
            return (ObjectPropertyBase)Activator.CreateInstance(
                field.FieldType,
                new object[] { }
            );
        }
    }
```

**Example:**

Comment: I could be off here but looking at your code on PasteBin line 32 you are checking if interface.Any == type(IList) if it's dynamic shouldn't be checking to see if it's of type `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`

Comment: The Value itself is not dynamic. typeof(T).IsGenericType (line 25) will tell me if it **could** be a List<T>, so then on line 32 I am checking to see if the T Value is supposed to be a list...

Comment: Could you post your calls to method `SetValueFromParams`? I tried your code and Value isn't null

Comment: I think that your CreatList method should be creating something that returns Generic 
`List<dynamic>` not IList something like this 
`protected T CreateList<T>(T parameter)` is what I am thinking

Comment: Added my method call for you erikscandola

Comment: since you are using a Generic class you would do some thing like this 
`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider someObj = new ObjectProperty();` but your call needs to allow for the Generic Type in the `= new portion`

Comment: Well the issue with that is, I am using reflection to also create the instance of ObjectProperty<T> to automate the process a bit (alot less code to write).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.. There was nothing wrong with my reflection code, but rather the code that was calling the "SetValueFromParams" method. I was not first checking to see if the C# object's field of ObjectProperty was null first before overwriting it with a new instance (and therefor a new List).

The fix:

```
public void Parse(string[] Params)
{
    // Fetch our property that we are setting the value to
    FieldInfo prop = this.GetType().GetField("IsExample");
    ObjectPropertyBase obj;

    // Get the value that is set
    var value = prop.Value.GetValue(this);

    // If the value is null, then we create a new object property instance
    if (value == null)
        obj = ObjectPropertyBase.Create(prop.Value);
    else
        obj = (ObjectPropertyBase)value;

    // Set Values
    obj.SetValueFromParams(Params);
    prop.SetValue(this, obj);
}
```

Thank you everyone who took the time to have a look at my question!